# Different scale for different parts of coordinate axis Y

Tags: plotting, logarithmic-scale

I have a list of points, like:

> {{0,2.17},{1,1.07},{2,0.53},{3,0.25},{4,0.11},{5,0.03},{6,0.002},{7,-0.015},{8,-0.0227},{9,-0.0250},
>   {10,-0.024675}, {part tends to zero}}

Ok, I would like to plot this data and, as it is easy to notice, without some manipulations with scale this picture will be not informative. I tried to combine ListLogPlot and take Abs from negative values of my data, but, unfortunately, the attempts failed. How can I do Log scale on the positive part of Y-axis and usual(without scale transformations) scale on the negative part of Y-axis?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's wrong with `{#[[1]], Sign@#[[2]] Abs@Log10@Abs@#[[2]]} & /@ data // ListPlot`? You can do `If[#[[2]] > 0, {#[[1]], Log10@#[[2]]}, #] & /@ data // ListPlot`, but I like the first version more.

Comment: Why not to change the origin to move your negative data to positive ones and cheat the marks by renaming the ticks?

Answer (score 1):

not exactly what you asked for , but one way to present such data is a log plot of absolute value, color coding the negatives..

```
data = Table[{i, Exp[RandomReal[{-5, 3}]] - 0.02}, {i, 30}];
ListLogPlot[If[#[[2]] <= 0, Style[# {1, -1}, Red], #] & /@ data, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

another approach, make essentially two plots:

```
opts = Sequence[PlotRange -> {{0, 30}, Automatic}, 
   ImagePadding -> {{60, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
   Frame -> True];
GraphicsColumn[{
  ListLogPlot[Select[data, #[[2]] > 0 &], opts],
  ListPlot[Select[data, Abs[#[[2]]] < .2 &], opts]}, Spacings -> -20]
```

[image]